# dart class hierarchy error - 'a' doesn't extend 'b' Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'b'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code:

```
class GroceryItemRepository extends ARepository<GroceryItemDomainEntity, int> {
  GroceryItemRepository(IHttpDataSource httpDataSource)
      : super(httpDataSource, 'GroceryItems');
}
```

Which causes this compile-time error:

```
'GroceryItemDomainEntity' doesn't extend 'ADomainEntity<GroceryItemDomainEntity, int>'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'ADomainEntity<GroceryItemDomainEntity, int>'
```

I can't tell why `GroceryItemDomainEntity` doesn't  extend `ADomainEntity<GroceryItemDomainEntity, int>`.

Here is the class hierarchy:

```
abstract class GroceryItemDomainEntity extends AVeganItemDomainEntity
    implements _$GroceryItemDomainEntity {

abstract class AVeganItemDomainEntity
    extends ADomainEntity<AVeganItemDomainEntity, int> {

abstract class ADomainEntity<EntityType, IdType> extends AEntity<EntityType>
    implements IDomainEntity<EntityType, IdType> {

abstract class AEntity<EntityType> implements IEntity<EntityType> {
```

It works when I declare `GroceryItemDomainEntity` as:

```
abstract class GroceryItemDomainEntity extends ADomainEntity<GroceryItemDomainEntity, int>
```

But I need `GroceryItemDomainEntity` to contain the members of `AVeganItemDomainEntity`. Why does `GroceryItemDomain` entity not extend `ADomainEntity<GroceryItemDomainEntity, int>`?

EDIT - sorry I missed this class:

```
import 'package:vepo/src/common/constants/environment_constants.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/data/data_sources/remote/i_remote_data_source.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/domain/common/domain_entity/a_domain_entity.dart';

import 'i_repository.dart';

abstract class ARepository<EntityType extends ADomainEntity<EntityType, IdType>,
    IdType> implements IRepository<EntityType> {
  ARepository(this.httpDataSource, this.$baseUri);

  final IHttpDataSource httpDataSource;
  final String $baseUri;

  @override
  Future<EntityType> $fetch() {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<EntityType> $save({EntityType entity}) {
    var uri = $baseUri;
    if (entity.id != null) {
      uri = uri + '${entity.id}';
    }
    final Uri theUri = Uri(path: '${EnvironmentConstants.of().apiUrl}/$uri');
    return httpDataSource.post<EntityType>(theUri, body: entity);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you add `ARepository` class?

Comment: @Mol0ko yes i just added it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
AVeganItemDomainEntity extends ADomainEntity<AVeganItemDomainEntity, int>
GroceryItemDomainEntity extends AVeganItemDomainEntity
```

So `GroceryItemDomainEntity` extends `ADomainEntity<AVeganItemDomainEntity, int>`.

In `GroceryItemRepository extends ARepository<GroceryItemDomainEntity, int>`, the `EntityType` is `GroceryItemDomainEntity`.

However

```
ARepository<EntityType extends ADomainEntity<EntityType, IdType>, IdType>
```

Since `EntityType` is `GroceryItemDomainEntity`, `ARepository` expects `GroceryItemDomainEntity` to extend `ADomainEntity<GroceryItemDomainEntity, int>` but it instead extends `ADomainEntity<AVeganItemDomainEntity, int>`.

`AVeganItemDomainEntity` is a super class of `GroceryItemDomainEntity`. So, `AVeganItemDomainEntity` cannot be used where `GroceryItemDomainEntity` is expected. But the other way is possible.

This requires changing what `EntityType` extends in `ARepository`. A possible solution I can think of is to use a concrete base type like `AEntity` or `ADomainEntity`.

```
ARepository<EntityType extends ADomainEntity<AEntity, IdType>, IdType>
ARepository<EntityType extends ADomainEntity<ADomainEntity, IdType>, IdType>
```

or just

```
ARepository<EntityType extends ADomainEntity, IdType>
```

Comment: Was the issue that generics specify an absolute type which cannot be "just any member of the family because a child technically is of the same type as the parent" but rather, has to be the exact type passed into the generic? I had a repeating member in my generic (`EntityType` in my `ARepository` declaration), and I was trying to pass `GroceryItemDomainEntity` off as a `AVeganItemDomainEntity` on the second repeat in `ARepository`, because it technically is one of the family. Which is not allowed, since I had specified `GroceryItemDomainEntity` as the absolute type of `EntityType`?

Comment: Yes. A child can have additional attributes and methods in addition to the parent. So you can pass a child (subclass) where a parent is required. But you cannot pass a parent (superclass) where a child is required, because according to the type, those additional properties can be accessed but the parent cannot provide those.